# Understanding problem with distributions of already observed data

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I need help interpreting the following problem:

Sociologic agency is making a research about the opinion of people about some decision of the government. 320 000 people are impacted by the decision and 6400 are not happy about it.

Randomly are selected 20 people and then interviewed. Let X be the number of not happy people among the interviewed.
Find the density of $X, EX, VX. P(X\le 3)=?$ Use approximation with appropriate distribution.

**My understanding:**

I understand that this is a binomial case where each person might be ok or not ok. If p is the probability for a person to not be happy with the decision, 1-p is the probability of a person being ok. So I know that

$P(X\le 3)$ is the cumulative binomial probability i.e. $P(X\le 3)=\sum^3_i{P(X=i})=\sum^3_{i=0}C_{20}^ip^i(1-p)^{20-i}$.

So what is p in that case? Is it ok, to assume that p is $\frac{6400}{320000}=0.02$?

Is it alright to assume that $EX = \sum^{20}_{k=0}P(X=k)k$?

Comment: It is OK to assume the $p$ you have calculated, in the absence of any further clarifying information.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thanks! Do you have any idea what "Use approximation with appropriate distribution." means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in the comments, "use approximation with an appropriate distribution" means that there is an exact distribution describing the situation, but computing values from it would be too hard, so a simpler distribution should be used instead.

The true distribution here is not binomial but [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) because the sample of 20 is drawn from the 320000 affected *without replacement*. This distribution is not commonly introduced in introductory probability classes, but since the sample size of 20 is much less than 320000 we can approximate it with a binomial distribution (which is sampling *with replacement*).

On the expected value of the distribution, your formula is correct, but you should be using properties of the approximation you have chosen to calculate it rather than relying on first principles. The same applies for the variance.

Comment: "but you should be using properties of the approximation you have chosen to calculate it rather than relying on first principles. The same applies for the variance." I don't quite get that, can you rephrase or give me an example? 
Thanks!

Comment: @NikolaShahpazov Returning to the expected value asked for, what I mean is that your formula for $EX$ is correct. However, carrying through the calculation using _that_ formula would be tedious without a computer, and this encourages you to use the properties of the binomial distribution instead for $EX$. In this case, $EX=np$ for a binomial distribution of sample size $n$ and success probability $p$.

Comment: Ah, got it! Thank you very much! So, for the expected value I use $EX = np$, for the variance $VX=np(1-p)$ and I assume I'm done with the problem.